# ruby rspec conversion from "should" to "expect" with block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm handling a set of rspec programs and pc seems to be forcing me to convert "should" questions to "expect". 
Have been able to handle most, but having problems with the following rspec setup.

Most of the other 'should' formatting involves an answer should == something and is easily converted to expect(passed_in_value).to eql(returned_value).
In this case though, I believe it is passing in a block to add to a given number, however, i and unable to just convert it to 
expect(end).to eql(6) or whatever the returned value should be.

Take a look and if you have any thoughts, please pass them on

```
it "adds one to the value returned by the default block" do
  adder do
    5
  end.should == 6
end

it "adds 3 to the value returned by the default block" do
  adder(3) do
    5
  end.should == 8
end
```

Comment: My guess is that you upgraded to the new version of rspec. Have you looked at https://github.com/yujinakayama/transpec as it does a really good job of converting all your specs automatically

Comment: Hi Doon,  thanks for the link and the thought.  Know I need to probably do that, but have had problems migrating to newer versions in past and just wanted to get this so I could test my program.  Once done with all programs I need to do, will take you up on upgrading.. thanks again

Comment: i was just going by the PC is forcing me to convert should to expect.  that happens when you hit the new version. so figured you had already upgraded.

Answer (score 2):

There're several methods to do that.

```
result = adder(3) do
  5
end
expect(result).to eq(8)

expect do
  adder(3) do
    5
  end
end.to eq(8)

block = -> do
  5
end
expect(adder 3, &block).to eq(8)
```

Example from comments with [respond_to](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/respond-to-matcher):

```
it "has a #sum method" do 
  [].should respond_to(:sum) #old syntax  
  expect([]).to respond_to(:sum) #new syntax
end
```

Comment: thanks Alex....  used first one and worked like a charm..  or at least the code I wrote to test it worked.  Certainly appreciate the help..

Comment: doing a bunch of rspec problems.  only one or 2 more possible issues regarding the should/expect conversion question.. here is another:**********          describe "#sum" do
    it "has a #sum method" do
      expect([]).to eql(true).should respond_to(:sum)
    end         *********  i guess another general question regarding this test...  could you explain either in general terms or pretty precisely exactly what they are looking for?  again appreciate the help

Comment: Oh, you mixed expect and should in one statement. Could you rewrite it with only should? Because I can't understand it.

Comment: describe "#sum" do
    it "has a #sum method" do
      [].should respond_to(:sum)
    end

Comment: In this case you can check my answer as right answer by clicking on the checkmark)